# `python -m ensurepip --upgrade` does not seem to be upgrading pip and setuptools

Tags: python-2.7, pip, homebrew, setuptools, python-3.4

I am on a Mac running Yosemite (Mac OS X 10.10.1) and [homebrew](http://brew.sh) installed python and python3 and `python -m ensurepip --upgrade` does not seem to be working as I would have expected.

`python -m ensurepip --upgrade` does not upgrade pip or setuptools.

`pip install --upgrade pip setuptools` upgrades pip to 6.0.7 and upgrades setuptools to 12.0.5.

Same results with Python3.  Do I misunderstand the purpose of [ensurepip](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/ensurepip.html)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ensurepip.html):

> This module *does not* access the internet. All of the components needed to bootstrap `pip` are included as internal parts of the package.

and (emphasis mine):

> To ensure the installed version of `pip` is at least as recent **as the one bundled with `ensurepip`**, pass the `--upgrade` option

Comment: Perfect!  Thanks much for clearing up my misunderstanding of ensurepip.  I will continue to use the `pip install --upgrade pip setuptools` to upgrade these tools because it does access the internet.

Comment: If you want to change the bundled version of setuptools and pip that come with ensurepip, you need to patch Python when you build it. The following will update the bundled versions before build. From then on, ensurepip and venv will use those versions: https://pastebin.com/sxVEeCb0

Comment: To patch the ensurepip module and have to work I also had to manually download the corresponding wheel.  On my system and python version that was executing `pip3.7 wheel -w . 'pip==19.2.2'` in directory `/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.4/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/ensurepip/_bundled`.