# Wrong version of pip in virtualenv

Tags: python, pip

I have defined a Python v-env and activated it through:

```
python3 -m venv myvenv
source myvenv/bin/activate
```

Before running this command, my pip3 version is 19.0.2, but once the command is run, the version changes to 18.1. What am I doing wrong?

[image: Here] is a screenshot from my terminal.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get "python -m venv" to directly install latest pip version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51720909/how-to-get-python-m-venv-to-directly-install-latest-pip-version)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%5Bvirtualenv%5D+old+version

Answer (score -1):

Editing this answer to serve as placeholder and preserve the comments, but:

This question is answered in this previous question, and is therefore a clear duplicate:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51721906/214150

The relevant section:

> It is an expected behavior. python -m venv calls python -m ensurepip to install pip and This answer shows that ensurepip would only install the bundled version even with --upgrade option. There isn't any official option to update the bundled pip and setuptools.

The referenced question from *that* question:

[`python -m ensurepip --upgrade` does not seem to be upgrading pip and setuptools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28210566/python-m-ensurepip-upgrade-does-not-seem-to-be-upgrading-pip-and-setuptools/28210626#28210626)

Comment: Hey) look at scrinshoots, when deactivate venv, I have last version of pip. But when I try to make venv, it builds with version 18.1 , not with latest

Comment: What do you get with `which python3` when you aren't in a virtual environment?

Comment: which python3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3
which pip3
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/pip3

Comment: So, i killed my problem. I just started to use 'virtualenv'. When i run virtualenv , i have latest version of PiP.
Hope it'll help someone:)

Comment: It's an interesting issue, and I'm sure lots of folks hit it. Glad you found a solution! Cheers!